# What do I need to send emails from my domain

Tags: iis, smtp, email, mail-server

I want to be able to send e-mail from my own domain (Domain.com) over Windows 2003 server, I tested my application and it's working alright on my local IIS.

But I don't know exactly what's needed to get it work for out side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Smells like IIS configuration to me. NPR ?

Comment: It would help if you tell how you send the mail. You must use some kind of interface (api). I would like to know what you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bashar, by "outside" I take it that you mean, "I want it to come from *domain.com*" (your domain).

To do this, you'll have to change the MX (mail exchange) record in the domain registration to point to the IP address of your SMTP server.  Of course, this will mean that any *existing* email server is no longer going to be processing email for this domain; **everything** will be routed to the IIS machine.  If this isn't suitable then you will not be able to truly send email that originates at your domain.

One workaround is to use your domain in the "Reply-to" and "FromAddr" of your email. Indeed, seeing your domain in the Reply-to field is enough to convince most people that the email did actually originate from there.  However, if the FromAddr points to an actual email server on one IP address and the mail actually originates from a different IP address (e.g. your IIS server) then many email relay servers will block it as likely spam.

Also, I recommend that you look into [AspNetEmail](http://www.aspnetemail.com) for managing email (really SMTP) programming. In addition to having a superb control, they also have a very rich body of technical support articles and a first-rate support program.  These people *really* know SMTP. You *could* read their content even without buying anything but a lot of the information is cast in terms that are specific to their control.  Of course, I also think it is a good idea to support vendors that help you.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't know exactly what's needed
>   to get it work for out side.

Work for outside? You want to send an email to bashar@domain.com from a computer that doesn't run the mail server? For this you will have to register the domain. Is that done?

Answer (score 1):

The email library of your programming language should have a facility to specify the outgoing SMTP server that handles emails originating from your domain. In the earlier days it used to be easy to just create a mail and send it from local SMTP server.

Ask your ISP if they provide access to a SMTP server for relaying emails. If that's done, you'll be able to send emails to any destination email address, without worrying about emails going to the junk folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got your domain registered, then to *send* mail you don't need anything except an SMTP client library and an SMTP server (i.e. at your ISP) that's willing to accept your mail and forward it to the destination.

To *receive* mail is somewhat harder.  For that you need:

- an SMTP server with a known (fixed) IP address
- MX records in the DNS pointing to that server
- mail client software, to download mail from the server

Answer (score 0):

I use gmail because I have so many domains, it has an easy to setup "send as" feature in the control panel and when you add a forwarder on your domain's email you are all set